# TreeView Nodes do not expand in IE

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, treeview

I have an ASP.NET `TreeView` populated with several levels of `TreeNode` objects. The nodes expand/collapse properly in all browsers except IE (I've tried IE 9 and higher.)

Here's what I've tried:

- I've already installed the hotfix to enable IE 10 support on my IIS server, as described [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)
- Setting UA-X-Compatible to `edge` in the page header

Strangely, I am still able to get the postback events from the `TreeView`, so I could expand/collapse the nodes manually if I need to. No javascript errors are generated in the IE developer tools window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this for a long while, I discovered that my `TreeNode` objects were the root cause of hte problem. I was using the `Value` property of the `TreeNode` to contain a serialized version of the object represented by the `TreeNode` (not super efficient I know -- but effective [the object is small anyway]).

Apparently, the data for the `Value` property needs to be encoded so that it can be passed into HTML/Javascript. This is **not documented** on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.value.aspx) for `TreeNode`.

**Solution:** Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)` and `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)` before getting/setting the `Value` property on the `TreeNode`. This will make things work in all browsers, including IE.